# Can I select an attachment via a dropdown choice populated from a library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a form that needs to point to particular agreement PDFs that is on a library on another sub site. Is there a way to create a dropdown choice list populate by the aforementioned to make as an attachment or anything similar?

I tried to use the hyperlink column but it doesn't bring the user directly to the correct folder to select from.

SharePoint 2010. Custom List.